# GSon fromJson fails for Arrays in Scala

Tags: scala, gson

I am using the Gson library from Scala. My JSON looks like

```
{"response":{"id":"xyz","userName":"foo","firstName":"foo","lastName":"bar","groups":["A", "B", "C"]}, "count":1}
```

To parse this I have written the following code

```
case class MyAdmin(id: String, userName: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, groups: List[String])
case class MyResponse(response: MyAdmin, count: Int)
```

My code to parse looks like

```
val respScala = gson.fromJson(responseString, classOf[MyResponse])
```

but I get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public scala.collection.immutable.List() with no args
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:111)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:210)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
    at com.foo.FlareCommandLine$.delayedEndpoint$com$foo$FlareCommandLine$1(FlareCommandLine.scala:28)
    at com.researchnow.FlareCommandLine$delayedInit$body.apply(FlareCommandLine.scala:17)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did some research and found that Gson does not handle scala collections very well. I replaced Gson with [Json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) ... now everything works fine and I am able to deserialize my json easily.

Someone has to tell Mr Alvin Alexander to update his blog. He is using a lot of old tools and code, but google will always point to his blog.